# Spotlight icon missing on Yosemite

Tags: macos, spotlight

The Spotlight icon isn't showing up in the upper right; even if I try to launch it manually from core services, nothing happens. I'm running Yosemite.

How can I get the icon back?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you it did for me!
Use Terminal

```
sudo chmod 755 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search
```

Then type in the following command:

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

After issuing these two commands, you'll notice that the Spotlight application will re-appear in the menubar of OS X.